# Initialisation of MapFragment in Activity Failing

Tags: android, xml, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I use the following XML code to create a MapFragment:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.hashcoder.eegoomain.CustomerHomeActivity"/>
```

And in my `onCreate()` method, I use the following code to initialize the map:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_home);
    createNavigationDrawerFunction();
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);  }
```

But, when I run this code on my phone (Redmi Note 4), it shows the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hashcoder.eegoomain/com.hashcoder.eegoomain.CustomerHomeActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #61: Binary XML file line #61: Error inflating class fragment
```

And this code works fine in other devices. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: your fragment(s) extends FragmentActivity instead of the regular Activity

Comment: sorry.. i didn't understand.

Comment: I didn't extend FragmentActivity. I extend AppCompatActivity